# how to block random calls from outside

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

running nodemon with express on my api domain
i keep getting random calls apparently from outside
kinda ruins my work flow... :)

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
3000 ok
mongo ok
GET /article.asp 404 3.246 ms - 150
GET /cintact.htm 404 0.380 ms - 150
GET /mainpage.html 404 0.197 ms - 152
GET /wan.asp 404 0.238 ms - 146
GET /aben.htm 404 0.220 ms - 147
GET /diispostmaster.asp 404 0.191 ms - 157
GET /molu.asp 404 0.192 ms - 147
GET /xz.asp 404 0.215 ms - 145
GET /server.asp 404 0.166 ms - 149
GET /admin_softdl.asp 404 0.251 ms - 155
GET /mda.htm 404 0.246 ms - 146
GET /_.htm 404 0.207 ms - 144
GET /gh.txt 404 0.221 ms - 145
GET /windowx.txt 404 0.214 ms - 150
GET /jc.html 404 0.208 ms - 146
GET /tongyi.html 404 0.189 ms - 150
GET /abb.asp 404 0.236 ms - 146
GET /zijing.html 404 0.207 ms - 150
GET /dsf.jsp 404 0.188 ms - 146
GET /zongg/daima.asp?id=65 404 0.857 ms - 154
GET /200861912234469.asp 404 0.254 ms - 158
GET /loveyun.asp 404 0.175 ms - 150
GET /z.htm 404 0.201 ms - 144
GET /xxoo.txt 404 0.182 ms - 147
GET /dd.txt 404 0.155 ms - 145
GET /anti-microsoft.html 404 0.204 ms - 158
GET /ckfinder/userfiles/files/robots.txt 404 0.188 ms - 174
GET /test.txt 404 0.205 ms - 147
GET /hacked.asp 404 0.220 ms - 149
GET /text.txt 404 0.190 ms - 147
GET /gha.asp 404 0.204 ms - 146
GET /hnboy.asp 404 0.224 ms - 148
GET /the.htm 404 1.513 ms - 146
GET /sear.asp 404 0.182 ms - 147
GET /010.txt 404 0.192 ms - 146
GET /aa.asp 404 0.225 ms - 145
GET /2009091519484277962.htm 404 0.209 ms - 162
GET /jyhack.com.txt 404 0.223 ms - 153
GET /3.asa 404 0.265 ms - 144
GET /ccs.txt 404 0.206 ms - 146
GET /sc201052034222.asp 404 0.234 ms - 157
GET /xt.asp 404 0.198 ms - 145
GET /error.asp 404 0.217 ms - 148
GET /hacker.aspx 404 0.241 ms - 150
GET /ab.php 404 0.187 ms - 145
 GET /images/log.php 404 0.205 ms - 153
 GET /homepage.htm 404 0.230 ms - 151
 GET /xt.html 404 0.180 ms - 146
 GET /junior.asp 404 0.205 ms - 149
 GET /net.asp 404 0.183 ms - 146
 GET /db.txt 404 0.213 ms - 145
```

.....list goes on and on................................

should i add extra security or just bloc the massages?
thanks for any advice : )

Comment: you can block some ip

Comment: cool, how do i find out in nodejs where its coming from?

Comment: You can use CORS and make it limited to only your website, but I was wonder how this can be..

Comment: thanks @mandaputtra seem like a good solution while dev this api, been making me crazy lately